# Use Smartphone as gateway to internet for my local network (Not smartphone hotspot!)

Tags: router, wifi, gateway, android, access-point

Am I able to use my Android smartphone with 4G LTE internet access as some kind of gateway to internet?

I need anyone who is connected to my local network made with Wi-fi router to be able to access internet.

My Android phone is also connected to this network by Wi-fi.

I do not mean Wi-fi HotSpot on phone or WDS. Those are useless to me.

My phone is rooted so I am able to make some routing there if nessesary.

Is it even possible?

[image]

Comment: What you say you want is exactly what a hotspot is! Why then do you say you don't want it? This is contradictory.

Comment: I want working home system (because of IoT devices), but without Internet. When I arrive to home I want to connect my phone and give all devices in network Internet.

Comment: That's a hotspot and it's already built in to your phone. Just turn it on.

Comment: A hotspot requires all devices to connect to the phone's ad hoc WiFi network. That's a limitation. As the author states, The goal should be to use the phone as a gateway to an existing lan/WiFi network.

Comment: I've written a working answer for the same [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/246574). Hope it helps.

Comment: @MichaelHampton you realise there's a difference between a device hosting a network (hotspot) and joining an existing one to provide a service (gateway), right? Good luck plugging your ethernet devices from your home network into a hotspot

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, though your Asus router may not support it.

Your picture is actually close to what you need. One correction is you need two wifi networks:

- "hotspot" network. You put your phone into hotspot mode and have your router connect to it as a client.
- "client" network - is a "regular" wi-fi network. Your router will act as access point and all other devices will connect to it. (Note: your phone won't connect to this network).

Then you need to configure your router to use "hotspot" network as gateway for all devices from "client" network. It'll probably involve NAT in IPv4 and potentially some tricky subnetting or address translation in IPv6.

Update: here's the picture: [image: Using phone as gateway]

Answer (score 0):

A proposal: You can use your phone connected through usb cable (usb tethering) to a server acting as router, firewall, even proxy. The usb connection will make a new usb ethernet interface, Internet facing, another interface, NIC or WLAN can connect to Asus wifi and provide access to the Internet to all your WiFi network.

Else, as Michael Hampton mentioned, you just do the same thing but with added complexity. Perhaps you need many concurrent connections, that's a scenario I can think of where there's a point connecting to a dedicated device for the task, than to mobile phone AP.

Comment: I dont want  many connections but I need working home network without internet access and get internet access when I connect phone.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, a phone as a hotspot is technically *a* gateway, but it's a super limited one. For instance, I cannot stream to my chromecast using my phone and phone as a hotspot because chromecast cannot connect to my hotspot network and I can't modify any of the network settings beyond the password.

I believe the solution would be to get an access point and then connect that to a router. You should be able to wirelessly receive and relay the phone data connection through ethernet on to the router.

Then it aught to be the same as if you're plugging in a modem, and you have complete control over this new network and can do MAC address filtering, port forwarding, network analysis, and all that fun stuff.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>If the stipulation that the phone must be connected via wifi, or you don't have an already running windows machine, this answer wont be helpful to you, however;</sub>

If you use a USB cable and connect it to a windows machine, like a laptop (with an ethernet port) you don't use or something, hook it up and in the same place you usually select "share device files" in android instead select "tether internet".

Now in windows open up Network Connections (hit start and run `ncpa.cpl`) and right-click properties for your phone's provided internet connexion. Under the Sharing tab, hit "Allow...users to connect", and in the dropdown select the ethernet port.

Connect your ethernet to your router's WAN socket, and in your router ask it to use Ethernet WAN (disable VLAN) with DHCP routing (autodetect everything and enable NAT).

Your router will act as a gateway as normal, thinking your laptop is a dedicated WAN device like with some fibre-optic solutions use. All routers should be capable of this, don't forget to tell the machine not to fall asleep.